# Tkinter problem creating button to collect text from user

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, nameerror, tkinter-entry

I am new to Tkinter, and am trying to create a hangman app. I have already created a command-line version, so I thought it would be a nice beginning project. When learning I was told to use window.mainloop() for creating/updating, but my program contains a while loop, and so that hasn't worked. I am not able to type into the textbox i have created at all and when I click the button, it gives me a NameError saying textEntry in my click() method is not defined. Any help or guidance of where else to look would be much appreciated. Thanks! My code is posted below

```
from tkinter import *
from random import choice

def click():
        guess = textEntry.get()
        return guess
def main():
        input_file = open('hangman_word_list.txt','r')
        word_list = input_file.read().split()
        window = Tk()
        window.title("Play Hangman!")
        window.configure(background="black")
        p1 = PhotoImage(file='h1.gif')
        p2 = PhotoImage(file='h2.gif')
        p3 = PhotoImage(file='h3.gif')
        p4 = PhotoImage(file='h4.gif')
        p5 = PhotoImage(file='h5.gif')
        p6 = PhotoImage(file='h6.gif')
        Label(window,image=p1,bg="purple").grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=4)
        word = choice(word_list)
        correctList = list(word)
        lettersLeft = len(word)
        hiddenWord = ('*' * lettersLeft)
        wrongGuessList = []
        lives = 6
        again = True
        nowPhoto = p1
        guess = 'empty'
        while lettersLeft > 0 and again == True:
                Label(window,text="Your word is "+hiddenWord ,bg="gray",fg="purple",font="none 12 bold").grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)
                Label(window,text="Enter a letter: " ,bg="gray",fg="purple",font="none 12 bold").grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)
                textEntry = Entry(window,width=5,bg="white")
                textEntry.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=W)
                guess = Button(window,text="Guess",width=5,command=click).grid(row=3,column=2,sticky=W)
                window.update()
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mainloop()` listens continously for any hook that you have defined, which means you don't have to worry about that. Just define the right hooks, like the button command.

I introduced a nicer way to handle the images by putting them in a list and then reducing the list for each image requested. This makes it easier to update the image.

Then put all processing, like checking if a uessed letter is in the word etc. in the `click()` function.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

# Make a list of all the pictures
pic_list = ['h6.gif','h5.gif','h4.gif','h3.gif','h2.gif','h1.gif']

img = PhotoImage(file=pic_list.pop())       # Get image from list of images
hangman = Label(window, image=img)          # Save reference to the Label as 
hangman.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=4)   #       you will update it later

# I simplified the word selection a bit
word = 'Wensleydale'

correctList = list(word)
lettersLeft = len(word)
hiddenWord = ('*' * lettersLeft)
wrongGuessList = []
guess = 'empty'

# Build the rest of the GUI
Label(window,text="Your word is " + hiddenWord, bg="gray", fg="purple",
      font="none 12 bold").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, columnspan=4)
Label(window,text="Enter a letter: ", bg="gray", fg="purple",
      font="none 12 bold").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
textEntry = Entry(window, width=10, bg="white")
textEntry.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W, columnspan=3)

def click():    # Callback function
    guess = textEntry.get()

    # Put all other processing here. 

    # Updating the image
    img = PhotoImage(file=pic_list.pop())   # Get next image from list
    hangman.configure(image=img)            # Replace image in label
    hangman.image = img             # Keep reference to the new image

# Create button and associate it with the command callback function
guess_button = Button(window, text="Guess", width=5,
                      command=click).grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W)

window.mainloop()   # Will loop continously listening for buttonpress
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to  enter text by using the mainloop() as you suggested and the photo sorting is much neater. I am still struggling with the NameError though. Within my click() method it is saying textEntry is not defined. typically I would add it as a parameter but that is not an option it seems for creating a button since there are no parenthesis following the command method. Do you have any idea what this could be? I have tried moving it before/below the Button but am lost outside of that.

Comment: My code does not produce that error (for me at least...). Can you please provide the code that gives you this error.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, a while loop is not recommended for use when it comes to using tkinter module as the window would be running on the main thread. Logically, when using buttons, you can use if statements so that it won't trigger a specific part of code until `lettersLeft > 0 and again == True`. And the use of variable `textEntry` in a function is obviously not available to Python because there is no declaration of it. So you either pass the variable as argument or declare a global variable.

Here is what I would think of:

```
    from tkinter import *
    from random import choice


    def get_wordlist():
        return open("Hangman word list.txt", 'r').read().split("split by something here.")


    class Hangman(Frame):
        def __init__(self, master=None):
            Frame.__init__(self, master)

            self.master.title("Hangman")
            self.master.configure(bg="black")

            self.wordlist = get_wordlist()

            self.p1 = PhotoImage(file="h1.gif")

            self.word = choice(self.wordlist)
            self.hidden_word = list("".join("_" for x in word))
            self.wrong_guess = []
            self.lives = 6

            self.word_display = Label(window, text=str(*(hidden for hidden in hidden_word)), image=p1, bg="purple", fg="white")
            self.word_display.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4)

            Label(window, text="Enter a letter: ", bg="gray", fg="purple", font="none 12 bold").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

            self.entry = Entry(window, width=5, bg="white")
            self.entry.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="W")

            self.guess = Button(window, text="Guess", command=lambda: button_action(self))
            self.guess.grid()

            self.again = False

        def button_action(self):
            user_input = self.entry.get()

            if len(user_input) == len(word):
                for i in range(len(word)):
                    if word[i] == user_input[i]:
                        self.hidden_word[i] = word[i]

                if "_" not in self.hidden_word:
                    self.word_display.config(text="You won! The correct word was: " + self.word)
                    self.after(3000, self.quit())
                else:
                    self.word_display.config(text="Guess not correct! " + str(*(hidden for hidden in hidden_word)))
                    self.lives -= 1
            else:
                self.word_display.config(text="Guess not correct! " + str(*(hidden for hidden in hidden_word)))
                self.lives -= 1

            if self.lives <= 0:
                self.word_display.config(text="You lost! The correct word was: " + self.word)
                self.master.after(3000, self.quit())
```

Please note 2 things:

- Try not to create redundant variables
- Before even asking a question, please do look on [python tkinter docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/tkinter.html).

Comment: Thanks, the advice about while loops fixed my typing issue. I have read the documentation. Tkinter is still unfamiliar to me though and I was unable to sort through it in a way that was helpful to me. For the sake of simplicity due to this being my first tkinter project I hope to avoid creating multiple classes. My main issue is a NameError stating that textEntry is not defined in my click() method but the button creation offers no space for adding parameters. I defined textEntry in my main method. When following a tutorial this didnt cause any issue although the method is basically identical.

Comment: that is because it needs to be either passed as argument or must be a global variable.

Comment: Within the Button creation though I am  confused on how it is possible to add arguments without having parenthesis to enter them into?